# Why was Kate the only one subjugated by the Zygons?

Tags: doctor-who

In The Day of the Doctor, the Zygon go around stealing identities.

When a Zygon took Kate Steward's identity, she was subjugated:

[image]

Osgood mentions that the Zygon need to keep their victim subjugated to refresh the copied image.

Well then, why weren't the other victims also subjugated? Like Elizabeth and Osgood. Maybe because they managed to escape - but in that case, why were their Zygon counterparts capable of maintaining their images, if their victims were not subjugated?

And how come that after freeing Kate, the Zygon that copied her was still perfectly fine? Maybe there is a time limit - is that mentioned?

... and the Doctor's horse!

Comment: I understood this as well as there being a time limit. So there was no real need to keep the victims locked down somewhere, however this made it easier to take their place (and avoid the whole "two queens at once" for example) and to copy them once again later on (i.e. a time limit).

Comment: I think that what Osgood said about needing to refresh the image would imply that they have no trouble taking the form initially, but that after a while they need to have the being that they are copying subjugated in order to maintain the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They just need the source to be alive. They needn't be necessarily "subjugated". That's just to be safe so that both don't come up against each other by mistake.